# Use std::shared_ptr and std::any to create a non-templated data container with safety check

Tags: c++, c++17, shared-ptr

I am trying to implement a non-templated data container that can store some shared ptr to data of any type and allows the user to retrieve it. I have seen that using `std::shared_ptr<void>` as suggested in [this page](https://www.nextptr.com/tutorial/ta1227747841/the-stdshared_ptrvoid-as-arbitrary-userdata-pointer) seems to be working. The idea, to my understanding, is to have something like the following:

```
class Container {
 std::shared_ptr<void> data;
public:
 void set(const std::shared_ptr<void>& p) {data = p;}
 
 template<typename T>
 void get() {return std::static_pointer_cast<T>(data);}
};
```

However, the problem is that there isn't a way of checking if the data type user tries to get is the same as the data type being stored.

I would like to know, whether using features like std::any from c++17 or anything else can help add a safety check when getting data from the container.

NOTE: will be great to retain the API of the container class:

1. to store data into the container, call `set(/* std::shared_ptr<Any Type Here> */)`
2. to retrieve data from the container, call `get</* Desired Type */>()` and get a shared pointer to the desired type if successful.

Consider the stored data to be huge, so any copy of the data itself is not desired.

Assume the container itself does not need to be copyable/movable.

Edit:

1. How about replace `std::shared_ptr<void>` with `std::any`, then store `std::shared_ptr</* Any Type */>` into `std::any`? Is this a good practice?

Thanks.

Comment: It is possible, but the only way to achieve that defeats the purpose of what you're trying to do, templating `set()` and `shared_ptr` is strictly better than only templating `set()` and having a runtime check on whether `typeid` of `T` passed to `set()` is the same as that which is expected when calling `get()`.

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<std::any>` would work, in fact, you wouldn't need to add a class around it. I wonder what problem you are trying to solve? Does it really need to be a `std::shared_ptr` or would a `std::unique_ptr` be better?

Answer (score 1):

To me, your container looks like it's reimplementing the functionality of [any](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any). I would personally store the `shared pointer` inside the `any` so I could get arbitrary `set` and templated `get`. Below you can see an example:

```
#include <any>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Foo {
    public:
        int value = 1;
};
class Bar {
    public:
        int value = 2;
};

int main() {
    any x = make_shared<Foo>();
    cout << "type:" << x.type().name() << endl;
    
    try {
        auto y = any_cast<shared_ptr<Bar>>(x);
    } catch (const std::bad_any_cast& e) {
        cout << "Bad cast: " << e.what() << endl;
    }

    // y has the right type now
    auto y = any_cast<shared_ptr<Foo>>(x);
    cout << y->value << "\n";
}
```

Otherwise, if you want to implement your own container, you can achieve type safety using [dynamic casts for smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast). But as someone pointed out in the comments, describing what are you trying to implement would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

An idea I have used before when my team wasn't on C++17 yet and `std::any` wasn't available.

Have a non-templated base-class and a templated class that derives from that to hold the data item.  The base-class is non-tempalted, but has a virtual destructor so that it can be used with `dynamic_cast` - which is fundamental to detecting if the data type being retrieved matches the callers expectation.

I'm not sure if this solves your issue. But it certainly resonated with something I had done before.  Here's a work-up using your class.

```
struct ContainerItemBase
{
    ContainerItem() {}
    virtual ~ContainerItem() = default; // need at least one virtual method for dynamic_cast to work
};

template<typename T> struct ContainerItem : public ContainerItemBase
{
    ContainerItem(std::shared_ptr<T> item) : data(item) {}
    std::shared_ptr<T> data;
};

class Container {
    std::shared_ptr<ContainerItemBase> boxed;

public:

   template<typename T>
   void set(const std::shared_ptr<T> p) {
       boxed = std::make_shared<ContainerItem<T>>(p);
   }
 
   template<typename T> std::shared_ptr<T> get() {
       if (boxed != nullptr)
       {
           ContainerItemBase* pBase = boxed.get();
           ContainerItem<T>* pItem = dynamic_cast<ContainerItem<T>(pBase);
           if (pItem)
           {
               return pItem.data;
           }
       }

       // This is where you can log, error, assert, throw, or return null
       // to allow the caller to handle the invalid data expectation
       std::shared_ptr<T> empty;
       return empty;
   }
};
```